# UnboundLocalError when assigning function result to variable named the same as the function

Tags: python

Why am I getting

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'heatmap' referenced before 
>   assignment

in the below script on the line `heatmap = heatmap()`?

```
def heatmap():
    heatmap = "123"
    return heatmap

def run():
   heatmap = heatmap()
   return heatmap

print(run())
```

Comment: It's not too wise to name your functions and variables the same. You might want to use `heatmap = get_heatmap()` or `my_heatmap = heatmap()` in general.

Comment: `heatmap = heatmap()` implies that `heatmap` is a local variable (because there's an assignment), and it means to use `heatmap` (by calling it, on the right-hand-side) before the first time it is assigned in the function (which is this line, after the call). This is the classic pattern for `UnboundLocalError`. See the linked duplicate for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using same names for functions and for local variables. Should not do this.

This line:

```
heatmap = heatmap()
```

first declares new variable `heatmap`, thus shadowing function, and then tries to call `heatmap()` to initialize it. But at this moment there is already **no such function**, because from now it is a local variable

Comment: This is interesting, because I always though calculations were performed first, then the result was stored in the variable. Sounds like it's the opposite.

Comment: @Guimoute, that is **partially** right. First computation, then storage. But before computation, the result variable name is being occupied. Something similar to Pascal's `var` section.